# Workaround to add virtual tags around <td> using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using Jquery to create html templates I need, that will have some special format.

However, I'm trying to add a virtual tag `<vt></vt>` around a `<td>` inside a `<tr>` tag.

Something like this:

```
var x='<vt><td>content here</td></vt>';
$(elem).find('tr').html(x);
```

Unfortunately the result is

```
<tr>
<vt></vt>
<td>content here</td>
</tr>
```

Probably the DOM compilator forces Jquery to have elements into a certain correct format. Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: I think your intuition is right, and that the browser's DOM compiler is such that it's "fixing" the broken tags. I know that Chrome behaves this way.

Comment: The HTML specification says the only parent elements permitted for `<td>` are `<tr>` elements ([see here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/td.html)) and the only child elements permitted for `<tr>` are `<td>` and `<th>` elements ([see here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/tr.html)). Since jQuery resides in the browser, the DOM parser it's going to use is going to follow the specification...

Comment: You can try parsing it as XML instead and it'll work: `$($.parseXML('<tr><vt><td>content here</td></vt></tr>')).children()`

Comment: What is the use case for these tags? Hard to suggest workarounds without  a higher level overview of what is needing to be accomplished

Answer (score 0):

According to the [HTML5 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/tabular-data.html#the-td-element):

> **4.9.9 The td element**
>
> **Contexts in which this element can be used:**
>
> As a child of a tr element.

Note that this means a `td` tag cannot be a child element of a `vt` tag.

Potential workarounds would be to either put your `vt` tag within the `td` element, use the `td` element directly, or use `div` elements with CSS `display:table`/`table-row`/`table-cell` instead of `table`/`tr`/`td` elements.